# How to get class from the method implemented in abstract class

Tags: java, reflection, abstract-class, instantiation

Let's say I have an Abstract class as following:

```
public abstract class Abstract{
   public void mymethod() {

   }
}
```

And a class implementing it:

```
public class Implementation extends Abstract {

}
```

I'm calling the mymethod from Implementation class and inspecting it:

```
method.getDeclaringClass()
            .getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
```

This fails since the Declaring class is abstract so it can't be instantiated. I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve the calling class instead.

Comment: You don't need to instantiate the object to inspect the class. How are you getting the `Method` object in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the declaring class, use the actual class:

this.getClass()

Answer (score 0):

It works fine.

```
Class<Implementation> im = Implementation.class;
Method[] m = im.getMethods();
Object o = m[0].getDeclaringClass().getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
System.out.println(o.getClass());
```

Prints----

```
class com.<package>.Implementation
```

You can print methods in loop, I have just pasted for 1st method m[0]

Comment: What if the method is only in the super class, which is my case.?